# Please identify this twin-engine airliner

Tags: aircraft-identification

Could someone please identify this aircraft for me.

[image: DSC 8770]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

HI, This aircraft is Qantas Airbus A330-300

Manufacturer Serial Number (MSN)----->564

Age 14.9 Years

current registration---->VH-QPC

Test registration------>F-WWYQ

Production Site---->Toulouse (TLS)

Airframe Status--->Active

Enjoy, cheers !!

source:https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Airbus/A330/VH-QPC-Qantas/ZQNhDG

Comment: I can't see any way you could work out from the original image it's this particular A330? Also the photo and data just seems to be copied from here, you should cite your source: https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Airbus/A330/VH-QPC-Qantas/ZQNhDG

Comment: @PeterJ, definitely better to cite the source, but he was right... that's a Qantas' bird ;-) Look at the red under the tail on the fuselage and the reg. number under the left wing.

Comment: @PeterJ, the one in the question. :-)

Comment: I concede that it is a Qantas jet. But Qantas owns 28 A330's. How did you determine that it was this specific aircraft?

Comment: While waiting for al Maghraby to explain, I'm guessing that he drew his conclusion from the registration number under the left wing. Enlarging this reveals that it is VH- + three letters, first is O or Q, second P or B, third C or G. The only matches in Qantas's registrations are QPC and QPG. Don't know why it couldn't be VH-QPG.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri , Sorry for the late response, I do agree with your last comment regarding how I determined the registration. But as you said it could be VH-QPG.

Answer (score 6):

That appears to be an Airbus A330.

[image]